# Does Synchronized Blocks maintain FIFO run order and can two blocks be reordered?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, synchronized

The first question is simple.

Say Java runtime has encountered three synchronized blocks with the same lock.

It sees bloc one first and grabs the lock and meanwhile it is running it encounters block two first and three next and both fail to obtain the lock.

Now block one finished and releases the lock so does this guarantee that block two will be the one to grab the lock and execute first since it tried to grab the lock before block three?

Next, say we have a method that has two synchronized blocks. Is it possible that block 1 which comes before block 2 might be reordered to run after block 2?

In the case they share the same lock, I am guessing the answer is no, but that might be wrong. Also what if they do not share the same lock?

Comment: What even is your question asking? I'm assuming that you're referring to successive blocks of code but they could possibly be nested or a combination of both... Please provide at least a sample of what you're talking about.

Comment: _""It sees bloc one first ..._  This is too vague to be meaningful.  For synchronized anything to have meaning you must have more than one thread, so (a) reframe your question in terms of threads, and (b) provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the situation you are asking about.

Comment: Ivans answer answers the first question. I was wondering if synchronized blocks guarantee FIFO acquire of locks based on who waits first. From the java docs on Semaphore

The constructor for this class optionally accepts a fairnessparameter. When set false, this class makes no guarantees about the order in which threads acquire permits.

When fairness is set true, the semaphore guarantees that threads invoking any of the acquire methods are selected to obtain permits in the order in which their invocation of those methods was processed (first-in-first-out; FIFO).

Comment: I guess next time I will elaborate more, it was just hard to do so since I am on my phone.

Once I get home I will update the second part of the question since Ivan answered the first.

Comment: On second thought I think Ivans answer answers the second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

synchronized blocks do not provide fairness guarantees which means that if thread A acquired lock and then threads B and C are waiting for the same lock there is no guarantee which of them will first acquire lock when thread A releases it.
Also JIT compiler could decide to merge adjacent synchronized blocks which use the same lock object. Also JIT could remove synchronization if no other thread will ever use it like this

```
synchronized (new Object()) {}
```

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10185/

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I tried not to be vague but I guess I failed at conveying my thoughts. Glad you understood though

Comment: Since the JIT compiler can merge those synchronized blocks and the inside of synchonized blocks can be reordered, I believe you are saying yes it can be reordered. Also a even stronger statement that the synchronized blocks can be removed, should also imply that. Am I right?